# Existence of an indicator function in finite field notation

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields, field-trace

The indicator function on a set $A$ is a function $1_A:A\to \{0,1\}$ defined by $$1_A(x)= \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } x\in A \text{ and}\\
0 &\text{if } x\notin A. \end{cases}$$

More specifically, if $L$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, the above notation holds. If $L$ corresponds to a general finite field, is there a finite field notation of the indicator function using for example the trace function or similar?

Comment: Perhaps I am being a bit naïve, but what's the problem with this definition in any field of characteristic $p > 0?$

Comment: The indicator functions of $(n-1)$-dimensional $\Bbb{F}_2$-subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ are exactly the functions $x\mapsto tr(ax)$, $a\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ some non-zero constant. For lower dimensional subspaces it becomes a bit more complicated. Write the subspace as an intersection of codimension one subspaces etc.